# Not able to access all the partition of system's hard disk in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, chgrp

I have made three partitions of my PC's hard disk. I have installed ubuntu in one partition, and the other two are empty, but these two partitions of disks are not opening in Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you format the "empty" partitions with a file system? What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `disks`

[image: hee]

**Format** the required partition by hiting `wheel` shape in the image

Comment: @Takkat that is only example picture